# Organize Qt project files in folders, and simplify the includes

Tags: qt, build, project-organization

**Brief**

How do I tell my sub-project which are its subdirectories, in `pro` file, and not have to prefix the subdirectories in each `#include` directive ?

**Problem description**

I have a large project, containing multiple libraries. Also, I am looking at one library that has a large number of classes. I am trying to organize it in such a way that it is easier to see everything at a glance.

I am using Qt Creator. The only way to make the logical grouping I am thinking of, is to create folders.

[image]

The "pro" file looks logical:

```
SOURCES += sample.cpp \
    class1.cpp \
    class2.cpp \
    interfaces/interface1.cpp \
    interfaces/interface2.cpp
```

In each file that I must include one of the headers I must also add the folder:

```
#include "interfaces/interface1.cpp"
```

I would not give this a second thought, except...

For an outside library or application, I can add in their pro file (or include a pri file) to tell where the current library files are located:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Sample
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Sample/interfaces
```

This creates the magic: from any outside library or application, I don't need to prefix the include directive with the folder location.

```
#include "interface1.cpp"
```

I have not been able to make this work from the current project. I don't understand why, I would like to know how to make it so that I no longer need to ad the folder path in the include directives (while still keeping the visual logical organization of my files).

**Summary**

For the structure above, adding

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Sample/interfaces
```

In the po file for an outside project allows me to include files like this:

```
#include "interface1.cpp"
```

I want to be able to do the same from the current project files. Right now, I am forced to include files like this:

```
#include "interfaces/interface1.cpp"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create .pri file for subdirectory. And include .pri in .pro file.